# Do a VLOOKUP of a database that is too large to open in excel

Tags: ms-access, excel-formula, vlookup

I am trying to do a VLOOKUP query into an Excel file (File 1) with about 500,000 rows from another csv file (File 2) that has about 4.5 million rows. This second file is too large to fully load in Excel, and so I am unsure how to proceed.

I am attempting to import data from File 2 to File 1 based on matching the unique PointID identifier in Column B in both files. I also have File 2 in an Access database if that works better. I have tried indicating the 'table_array' index in File 1 without opening File 2, but am receiving an error message.

Is there a way I can iterate over File 2 like a VLOOKUP without opening it or receiving an error message?

Comment: You can query File 2 using `ADO`, either in Access or directly in the csv.  Lots of examples on SO

Answer (score 0):

If you've already got File 2 in Access I would import File 1 into Access as well. Make sure that File 1 has its PointID set as the Primary Key, then you should be able to use an Update query in Access to get the relevant values from File 2 into File 1. You would then export the updated File 1 data back to a new Excel file (if that's where you need it to be).

I can't think of an easy way to update the original File 1 directly. It doesn't work if you add File 1 as a linked table in Access because the data isn't updateable as far as I can tell (I did try this, but I am working on older copies of Excel/Access so maybe newer versions may allow it).